# TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating > 'e.relatedTarget.nodeName')

Tags: jquery, youtube-iframe-api

I need to get the data-video-id attribute and my code keeps returning a null when I request it.

## HTML

```
<script src="https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api"></script>
<script src="js/video.js"></script>

<a data-target="#myModal" data-toggle="modal" data-video-id="VDB65S6rCC0" >
   <div class="btn btn-success"> Open Modal 2</div>
</a>

<a id='video-player-1' href="#my_modal" data-toggle="modal" data-video-id="VDB65S6rCC0">Open Modal 1</a>
```

## video.js

```
  var tag = document.createElement('script');

  tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
  var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
  firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

  var player;
  function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('player', {
      height: '390',
      width: '640',
      videoId:  '{{no-video-id}}',
      events: {
      'onReady': onPlayerReady,
      'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
    }
                           });
  }


  // 4. The API will call this function when the video player is ready.

  function onPlayerReady(event) {

    $('.open-popup').click(function() {
      event.target.playVideo();
    });

    $('.close-popup').click(function(e) {
      player.stopVideo();
    });

  }

  // 5. The API calls this function when the player's state changes.
  //    The function indicates that when playing a video (state=1),
  //    the player should play for six seconds and then stop.
  var done = false;
  function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
    if(event.data === 0) {           
      $('.close.close-popup').click();
    }
  }
  function stopVideo() {
    player.stopVideo();
  }

 $(function () { 
 onYouTubeIframeAPIReady();
   $('#my_modal').on('show.bs.modal', function(e) {
      var videoId = $(e.relatedTarget).data('video-id');
      var x = new String(videoId);
      player.loadVideoById(x); 
      $("iframe[src^='https://www.youtube.com']").addClass("embed-responsive-item"); 
      alert("BOOM!");
  });

   $('#video-player-1').click(function(e) {
      var bookId = $(e.relatedTarget).data('video-id');
      alert($(e.relatedTarget.nodeName));

      var x = new String(bookId);
      player.loadVideoById(x);

      });
});
```

## ERROR:

When clicking the  to open a modal, the related target is null.

> TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating
>   'e.relatedTarget.nodeName')

`alert(e);` returns

> [object Object]

Also `$('#my_modal').on('show.bs.modal', function(e) {` does not seem to execute.

Comment: The [jQuery docs say](https://api.jquery.com/event.relatedTarget/) that relatedTarget is for when more than one element is involved, e.g. a mouseout or mouseover event where the cursor is moving from one element to another. That's not the case here. Why do you need relatedTarget? The current element will be `this`.

Comment: Not sure, but it worked when tested in JSFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/ssorabh/k7FC2/7324/, but when I moved it to my actual test site, it stopped working.

Comment: I tested, $(e.this) and it does not seem to work either.

Comment: Not e.this, just $(this)

Comment: @Rup $(this) does not seem to work either.

Comment: using $(this) in $('#my_modal').on('show.bs.modal', function(e) { breaks the function.